# Parameterising the parallel="methods" property in the suite tag of testng.xml

Tags: xml, testing, testng

I have a situation where i need to implement a switching mechanism on testng suite, to decide whether to run tests parallely or not.

Currently my testng.xml looks as following:

```
<suite name="XYZ" parallel="methods" thread-count="3">
    <test verbose="2" name="ABC">
        <classes>
           <class name="xx.yy">
               <methods>
                   <include name="test3" />
                   <include name="test2" />
                   <include name="test1" />
               </methods>
            </class>
           </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

My objective is to be able to specify something like :

```
 <suite name="XYZ" parallel="$PARALLEL_FLAG" thread-count="3">
```

where the $PARALLEL_FLAG can take values `methods` or `false` dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing exists out of the box, but you can manage it yourself with:

1. a xslt file which will preprocess the file, or
2. you can try to use an [`ISuiteListener`](http://testng.org/javadocs/org/testng/ISuiteListener.html) and modify the `parallel`attribute from `XmlSuite` there, depending on your own logic (but I didn't check if it is working).

Comment: As @Krishnan_Mahadevan proposed, prefer IAlterSuiteListener as listener

Comment: That worked great. Thanks, i am on testng 6.8.14 , maybe why i dont have IAlterSuiteListener. However thanks @Krishnan_Mahadevan.

Comment: Below is the code.

@Override
    public void onStart(ISuite iSuite) { 
        XmlSuite xmlSuite = iSuite.getXmlSuite();
        xmlSuite.setParallel("methods");
}

Comment: 6.8 is really old. You should considere to upgrade to 6.9.x (x will depend on your jdk version)

Comment: Upgraded now. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of [IAlterSuiteListener](http://testng.org/javadocs/org/testng/IAlterSuiteListener.html) which exposes the actual `XmlSuite` object before TestNG even begins to create suite workers for execution and thus giving you an opportunity to change whatever you would like to. This listener is exactly like all other listeners in terms of implementation etc.,

You just need to ensure that you wire your `IAlterSuiteListener` implementation via either `<listeners>` tag in a suite file (or) via Service Loaders. The only caveat is that you cannot wire in this listener implementation via `@Listeners` annotation.